# How get task items according to current sorting using rest api

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, task-list, ordering

In a task list, we can move up and down items, now I want get items according to current sorting using Rest API, not by ID, Title or other fields.

[image]

By default when I get the items without order option, items sort by ID:

```
http://example.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('tasklistname')/items?$select=Title
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden "Order" column that Microsoft uses behind the scenes when you move a task up or down in the view.  You can include that value in your `$select` and `$orderby`.
Unfortunately, that will likely only get you partway there if you are also "indenting" tasks to make some tasks child tasks.  SharePoint is apparently doing some additional JavaScript manipulation in order to render those items on the page, as child level tasks are getting assigned lower sort values.  So for example, in your screen shot above, if you included `$orderby=Order` your "task1" task would be first because it is a child, then "task3" and then "task2" would be in the same order you see in the UI.  I would appear that SharePoint is pulling child tasks off the list first in order to keep them hidden from the UI until their "parent" task is rendered.

Not sure what language/code you are using to execute the REST call, but you could potentially do something similar to what SharePoint is doing in that UI.  If you include `ParentID/Id` in your `$select` and `$expand=ParentID` you will know which items are child elements even if they are sorted at the top.  As you enumerate the items for rendering, if they have a `ParentID/Id` value, then save them in an indexable object instead of rendering them, then once your loop reaches an item that has no Parent, render that item and recursively look in you indexed object for children whose `ParentID/Id` matches the current task ID.  This is likely why SharePoint designed the `Order` column to put all children first in the sort order so that you know all child tasks are loaded before parent tasks are rendered, without having to make multiple REST calls.

`http://example.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('tasklistname')/items?$select=Id,Title,Order,ParentID/Id&$expand=ParentID&$orderby=Order`